# What does the ./ mean (dot slash) in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, files, filenames

For example, I can do the following

`touch a`

or

`touch ./a`

Then when I do `ls` I can view both, so what exactly is the `./` for?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572409/841108

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The dot-slash, `./`, is a relative path to something in the current directory.

The dot is the current directory and the slash is a path delimiter.

When you give the command `touch ./a` you say "run the `touch` utility with the argument `./a`", and `touch` will create (or update the timestamp for) the file `a` in the current directory.

There is no difference between `touch a` and `touch ./a` as both commands will act on the thing called `a` in the current directory.

In a similar way, `touch ../a` will act on the `a` in the directory above the current directory as `..` refers to "one directory further up in the hierarchy".

`.` and `..` are two *special directory names* that are present in every directory on Unix systems.

---

It's useful to be able to put `./` in front of a filename sometimes, as when you're trying to create or delete, or just work with, a file with a dash as the first character in its filename.

For example,

```
touch -a file
```

will not create a file called `-a file`, and neither would

```
touch '-a file'
```

But,

```
touch ./'-a file'
```

would.

Answer (score 24):

The `./` notation is useful when trying to run a script or other executable in the current directory. Unlike the Windows command prompt, Unix (and Unix-like systems like Linux) shells do not check the current directory for executables before checking the `PATH` environment variable, and Unix systems tend not to include `./` in the `PATH` for security reasons. By having to specify

```
./executable
```

rather than just

```
executable
```

the user is saying, "yes, I *do* want to run this executable in the current directory"

Answer (score 6):

This is called a relative path.

`.` represents the current working directory.  So if you are currently in `/home/jesse`, `.` is simply a link to `/home/jesse` so when you point to `./` you are really pointing to `/home/jesse/`