# Running python script on ubuntu machine using ./myscript.py

Tags: linux, scripting, python, executable

I am running a python script named myscript.py on ubuntu machine. I usually use python command to run python scripts as below.

```
python main.py
```

Recently, I downloaded a python script from a Github repository ( if need to look into the repository can find it at https://github.com/gsrivas4/mnist-gan) which asks to run script using './' as below.

```
./main.py
```

Running python scripts second way is new to me. I am confused about when can we use './' to run scripts and is this method to run scripts used for other languages as well. Usually, I would expect name of binary such as python which will start a process before I add the name of script. This script will be fed to the process. Also, I want to understand what is the meaning of './' when we run scripts. I feel this is trivial question, but could not find much help online.

I also tried making one of my python file executable and then ran it. However, running it using ./ gave me errors for any python library import commands.

Comment: Probably related: [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600/237982) and [What does the ./ mean (dot slash) in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397524/237982)

Comment: @Jesse_b my_script.py is just an example. I am running ./main.py. I will edit my question to make the point clear.

Comment: Does the python script you are getting errors with have a hashbang pointing to python?

Comment: @Jesse_b No there is not hashbang in my script which gives errors. I was unaware of hashbang. I am reading about it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` is simply a relative path indicating the current working directory.  When executing a file that is not in your `PATH` it's necessary to prefix it with either the full path or a relative path, `./` is the most simple method of doing this, but it would also work if you used a full path like `/path/to/script.py`

The reason your python script gets errors when you execute it as:

```
./script.py
```

rather than:

```
python script.py
```

is because you do not have a hashbang(shebang) interpreter line at the top telling it which interpreter to use when executing the script.  It's likely trying to execute it with bash or whatever shell you are using to execute the script.  (See [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/237982))

---

To get your script to execute properly using python add the following to the first line in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```