# What does / do?

Tags: linux, bash

I know that `/` stands for folder, but there is one thing I don't get.

Command to illustrate the problem:

```
mv ~/Documents/newfolder ./anothernamefolder
```

Why there is `/` here? What does it do? Why can't I type:

```
mv ~/Documents/newfolder . anothernamefolder
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ./ mean (dot slash) in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux) in the link there's a neat explanation to what you are enquiring about

Comment: You seem to understand what `/` is but are confused with the dot (`.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment's link ([What does the ./ mean (dot slash) in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux)), and as you correctly think, slash (`/`) is a directory "representation".

In your two examples, the slash represents different things though:

```
mv ~/Documents/newfolder ./anothernamefolder
```

move `newfolder` from `Documents` located under user home directory (`~`), to current directory (`./`) and name it `anotherfolder`.

In the second one

```
touch {jan,feb,mar,apr}_{2017..2019}/file{1..100}
```

you touch files in number of directories.

So for every directory specified in the command: `{jan,feb,mar,apr}_{2017..2019}` create files `file{1..100}`.

> Why there is "/" here? What does it do? Why I can't type:

As above, `./` is representation of current directory.

If you used

```
mv ~/Documents/newfolder . anothernamefolder
```

command, you'd get an error, as you'd be specifying ambiguous redirections:

```
$ mv ~/Documents/newfolder . anotherfolder
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

You could use dot `.` to move, but that would simply move folder called `newfolder` without changing its name.

```
$ mv ~/Documents/newfolder .
$ ls
newfolder
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. So basically I can understand mv ~/Documents/newfolder ./anothernamefolder as mv ~/Documents/newfolder ~/Desktop/anothernamefolder (in this example the . is a desktop) am I right?

Comment: yup, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

`/` *separates* directories (folder is a gui-term).

In the first argument to your `mv`-command `/`'s separate `~`, `Documents` and `newfolder`, signaling that each is a subdirectory of the previous.

The same is true for the second argument, saying that you want to move files to `anothernamefolder` which is a subdirectory of `.`. As `.` (in that context) means the current directory, `./` is unneeded.

Just removing the `/`, as you suggest, changes the meaning of the command, to say that you also (in addition to `~/Documents/newfolder`) want to move `.` to `anothernamefolder`. That is not possible and will cause `mv` to give an error.

Comment: No folder is an MS-Windows term. A bad metaphor. A thing can be in more than one directory (and so can files). A thing can be in only one folder, not true for files, on Unix file-systems, or NTFS.